# Is the limit infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> What is the value of the following limit 
>   $$\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{2\sqrt{x+5}}{x+1}=?$$
>   a) $1/2\qquad$ b) $-1/2\qquad$ c) $ 1/4\qquad$ d) $-1/4\qquad$

my try: i let $x+1=t$, so i get

$$\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{2\sqrt{x+5}}{x+1}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{2\sqrt{t+4}}{t}$$
$$=2\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{2\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4}}}{t}$$
$$=4\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\left(1+\frac{t}{4}\right)^{1/2}}{t}$$
then using binomial expansion for $|x|<1$, $(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2+\ldots$, i get
$$4\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1+\frac12\frac{t}{4}+\frac{(1/2)(1/2-1)}{2!}\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)^2+\ldots}{t}$$
$$=4\lim_{t \to 0}(\frac1t+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{t}{128}+\ldots)$$
here limit tends to infinity but my book says the limit  is $1/2$, I don't know how. please help me solve this limit. suggest me other method if any. thanks

Comment: It clearly doesn't exist. The denominator $ \to 0$ but not the numerator. And the sign of the denominator differs as $x$ approaches from the left and the right

Answer (score 3):

The written limit does not exist, as it goes to $-\infty$ from the left and to $\infty$ from the right, because the numerator goes to $4$ and the denominator to $0$.

There is something missing:
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{2\sqrt{x+5}-4}{x+1}
$$
is the most probable candidate to be the correct limit to compute.

Comment: One more typo in a textbook, I presume. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The number of typos in a book is a function with discrete values, decreasing with time, which never reaches the value $0$. `;-)`